# Error while accessing element of array in struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write an "ArrayList" program (Similar to the Java [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) that will expand automaticly using [`realloc`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm), so that the programmer won't have to worry about storage space in arrays. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ARR_DEFAULT_SIZE 20
#define INCR 10

#define ARRTYPE char // Files using this #undef this macro and provide their own type

typedef struct {
    ARRTYPE *arr;
    long size;
    long nextincr;
} arrlst;

arrlst *nlst(void);
void add(arrlst *, ARRTYPE);
ARRTYPE elmat(arrlst *, long);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    arrlst *lst = nlst();
    add(lst, 'h');
}

arrlst *nlst() {
    arrlst lst = { malloc(ARR_DEFAULT_SIZE), 0, ARR_DEFAULT_SIZE };
    arrlst *lstptr = &lst;
    return lstptr;
}

void add(arrlst *lst, ARRTYPE elm) {
    if (lst->size >= lst->nextincr) {
        ARRTYPE *tmp = lst->arr;
        lst->nextincr += INCR;
        lst->arr = realloc(lst->arr, lst->nextincr);

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof tmp; i++)
            lst->arr[i] = tmp[i];
    }

    lst->arr[lst->size++] = elm;
}

ARRTYPE elmat(arrlst *lst, long at) {
    if (lst->size < at)
        strerror(14);

    return lst->arr[at];
}
```

My problem is that whenever I run this, calling `add()` produces a segfault, and since most of the code in `add()` is skipped on the first time calling it, the line of error must be:

```
lst->arr[lst->size++] = elm;
```

And I don't know why this would segfault. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in `nlst` you return a pointer to a local variable, and local variables goes out of scope and "dies" when the function they are defined in returns. Using that pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*, which is a very common reason for crashes.

You have two solutions: Either `nlst` should dynamically allocate the `arrlst` structure and return that pointer. Or you pass in a pointer to an `arrlst` structure, thereby emulating pass by reference.

Comment: Thanks! I used dynamic allocation, and it worked fine.