# 2d Array Not Initializing Correctly in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create a 2d array in C. The following functions are helper functions. However, when I run the program, using d = 5, my output should be a 5x5 matrix, with values descending from 25 to 0. Instead I am getting...

```
-86 -87 -88 -89 -90 
-91 -92 -93 -94 -95 
-96 -97 -98 -99 -26 
-27 -28 -29 -30 -31 
-32 -33 -34 -35 -36
```

Why?

```
int* init()
{
    int arr[d][d];
    int* p;
    p = &arr[0][0];
    int r;
    int c;
    int place = 0;
    int num = d*d;
    for (r=0;r<d*d;r++)
    {   
       for (c=0;c<d;c++)
       {
           *(p + place) = num;
           num--;
           place++;
       }
    }
    return p;
}

void draw(int* p)
{   
    int r;
    int c;
    int num = 0;
    for (r=0;r<d;r++)
    {
        for (c=0;c<d;c++)
        {
            printf("%i ",*(p+num));
            num++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. your indexing is wrong in `init`; your outer-loop should break on the condition `r<d`, not `r<d*d`. 2. `arr` ceases to exist as soon as `init` returns, giving your omitted caller a non-derefererencable pointer, and efforts to dereference will invoke *undefined behavior*. 3. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be provided, which this is *not*.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35822841/5802468) for #2.

Comment: Much thanks, WhozCraig and Majora320. Fixed my outer loop and dynamically allocated array. Works fine now!